# Html5 video background, keep center of video in center

Tags: css, html, video

I am trying to keep a background video centered regardless of how big the user drags the video. It's currently cutting off the right side of the videos when i scroll smaller. Here's what I have:

```
<section id="home">
     <div class="video_shader"></div>
        <div class="video_contain">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" poster="img/still.jpg" id="bgvid">
              <source src="/realWebm.webm" type="video/webm" />
              <source src="/realdeal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="/reaOg.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            </video>
        </div>
</section>

.video_contain{
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

video {
min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

#home {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display:block;
position: relative;
}
```

I would like the center of the video to be the center of the page always, even if the sides get cut off - that's actually ideal if it happens that way. Would appreciate any help. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

here's how I typically do background video, and how I did it for the **[stre.am](https://stre.am/)** landing page:

```
.video_contain {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
}
```

[image: stream fs vid for mobile]

Comment: This works great until I hit mobile sizes. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't behave any differently at mobile sizes. make sure you don't have any media query styles interfering. I've attached a pic of what it SHOULD look like at mobile sizes.

Answer (score 30):

This is much shorter and worked for me.

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(calc((100% - 100vw) / 2));
}
```

Comment: Absolutely the best answer @Pezcraft. In my case, all I needed was to include two lines of your code and it worked perfectly for me.  Thank you so much for your contribution.

Comment: Works perfectly. I'm guessing you got the original code from W3Schools. All I did was add the transform property and my video is working exactly the way I want. Thanks!

Comment: This creates a weird overflow on the right side (video width > 100%).

Comment: Worked for me with Bootstrap 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

In my use case where I always wanted the video to cover the entire viewport (no matter if the viewport aspect ratio was bigger or lower than the videos), the above solution didn't work exactly how i intended. Instead, the following worked much better:

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.video-container > video {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1920/1080) {
  .video-container > video {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1920/1080) {
  .video-container > video {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

My video was 1920x1080, and this works in IE11 (didnt test lower) and beyond.

Comment: Worked best for me — also, this is an excellent use of media queries! I added overflow:hidden; to .video-container to prevent left/right scrolling on mobile

Comment: I would apply position:fixed on the .video-container as well.

Comment: very clean and robust

Comment: I added `min-width: 100%` and `min-height: 100%` to the `.video-container > video` selector, changed the `position` to `relative` and added a `overflow: hidden` to the video for our video-calling tool. Worked great. Thank you.

Comment: This worked where others didn't. I did not need the @media selectors at all, the left:50% and translate: -50% was what was really effective. It did help to hide overflow on the container as Luchspeter said.

Answer (score 10):

```
  .bg-video-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .bg-video-wrap > video,
  .bg-video-wrap > iframe {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: please add some description the next time, what the code is doing

Comment: Didn't even need the wrap. Just the 4 lines for the video tag. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party but I wanted to give a 2020 answer. Here's a simple solution that lets you have an HTML video both centered and responsive without being "fixed" positioned. It lets you start with a fullscreen intro and add some text right when you start scrolling. No scrollbars, no annoying things. As simple as that.

https://codepen.io/LuBre/pen/GRJVMqE?editors=1100

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-Family: Arial;
}

.video-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.video-text {
  z-index: 2; 
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.video-container h1, .video-container h2  {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.video-container h2  {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.page-content {
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="video-text">
    <h1>Catchy title</h1>
    <h2>Everyone loves catchy titles</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-content">
<h1>New paragaph</h1>
Some random text goes here...
```

Comment: I'm looking into this video stuff and am trying to figure out... how would you turn something like this into a carousel? Just wondering if there's an easy way

Answer (score 5):

Use `object-fit: cover;`

```
video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

just center it like any other element with position absolute

```
.video_contain {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
.video_contain {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: none;
}

#bgvid {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: visible;
  width: 1267px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me, keeping the video centered all the time and not worrying about the actual dimensions of the video

```
.video_contain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /** could be any size **/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
video {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tested above solutions and couldn't find **that** one, so here is mine:

```
video {
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```