# Fullscreen background video using VideoJS + React

Tags: css, html, reactjs, html5-video, video.js

Does someone try to use VideoJs player as a Fullscreen Background video using React ?

Previoulsy I've achieved this using regular html5 `video` tag as shown in this Code Pen's tutorial

For the rest of my side project, I need to be able to read MPEG Dash stream videos and I saw it can be *easily* done with VideoJS but not with regular `video` tag.

If there is no possibilities to achieve this, I can move to another player.

So do you folks have any clue or advise?

Cheers,

Bertrand

**edit :** If I remove the `video.js/dist/video-js.css` css stylesheet provided inside video.js NPM package the video is view in fullscreen but some interesting but unsightly details (in my case...) are displayed as shown in this [other screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juFLX.png)

*Disclaimer* :

- I'm not trying to build a fancy advertising web site with big and 
  ugly video ads
- I'm abecedary with React, Videojs and building front-end application in general

[Here is a screenshot showing the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0IF8.png)

and a (non working) code snippet  :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import videojs from "video.js";
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
import "./MainVideo.css";

export class MainVideo extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, {
            autoplay: false,
            controls: false,
            sources: [{
                src: "myFancyVideo.mp4",
                type: 'video/mp4'
            }]
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="fullscreen" div-vjs-player> 
                    <video ref={node => this.videoNode = node} className="video-js"></video>          
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default MainVideo;
```

```css
.fullscreen video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850657/1300562 or try `.vjs-tech { object-fit: cover; }` if you don't care about IE.

Comment: Great! I'll try it asap and let you know if it solve my problem. At the moment I decided to use Facebook API to get my streams. They use 'old school' Iframes instead of `video` tag. In the near future, I'll move back to dash stream with Video.js. That's my current goal.

Comment: If you need a plugin https://github.com/samAbeywickrama/reactjs-videobg