# How to: make my video background CENTERED & SCALABLE, no matter change in browser size?

Tags: css, video, background, html5-video, fullscreen

I can't figure out how to get the background video to be centered, no matter the size of the browser window. The video is only centered when the browser is expanded to take up the entire screen; 1920x1080; or thereabout.

I have tried some solutions I found here, but I can't get anything to work. I'm a graphic designer, but I can do basic basic code... and edit what other people have done, and follow simple instructions. I am stuck here and would greatly appreciate any help or advice. I am hoping there is a simple solution... ?   Thank you.

Below are the portions of code that I have now...

Here is the website: http://test2.scottyelle.com

The video BG in question is at the top of index.html  -  OW.mp4

I also looked at this question/answers - [Html5 video background, keep center of video in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850472/html5-video-background-keep-center-of-video-in-center)

```
.video {
position: relative;
height: 40rem;
overflow: hidden;

}
#myVideo {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

.video-content {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
color: #f1f1f1;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
}




<section class="video home-section home-full-height" id="home">

<video loop autoplay muted playsinline id="myVideo">
<source src="assets/images/Beach/OW.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="titan-caption">
<div class="caption-content">
<center>
<img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/logo.svg" height="300px" width="300px"></div>
</center>
</div>
</div>

</section>
```

I expect/need the video, OW.mp4, to be displayed centered and be scalable when users change browser window size and when the site is viewed on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick i use:

HTML

```
<div class="video_container">
    <video preload="auto" playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" id="heroVideo">
            <source src="path/to/video" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.video_container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Because this has to go in the back of body, make sure the absolute is relative the body( or the div that covers the bg).